# `dplyr` group_by column not found

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

Working on an RShiny app and am currently having trouble with `dplyr`'s `group_by()` function. I have two defined functions:

- `gather_info`: finds the category with the highest/lowest mean value
- `paste_info`: calls `gather_info` and returns the corresponding category and value

The purpose is to return a string that - given a data frame and categorical variable - states the highest- and lowest-performing category and value of said category.

Calling `gather_info` with the appropriate arguments works as expected. However, `paste_info` consistently returns:

```
Error in `group_by()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
✖ Column `grp.col` is not found.
```

**Here's a reproducible example, where the desired output of `paste_info` is "Given your data, your best performing group is Cat1 scoring 90% and your worst performing group is Cat2 scoring 20%."**:

```
gather_info <- function(df, grp.col, maxm) {
    df |> 
        mutate_if(
            .predicate = function(x) is.character(x),
            .funs = function(x) str_to_title(x)
        ) |> 
        group_by({{ grp.col }}) |> 
        summarize(percentage = round(mean(value, na.rm=TRUE) * 100, 2)) |> 
        arrange(desc(percentage)) %>%  # c'est un pipe
        {if (maxm) head(., 1) else tail(., 1)}
}

paste_info <- function(df, grp.col) {
    
    high_df <- gather_info(df, grp.col, maxm=TRUE)
    low_df <- gather_info(df, grp.col, maxm=FALSE)

    paste0("Given your data, your best performing group is ",
          high_df |> pull(grp.col), " scoring ", high_df$percentage, "%",
          " and your worst performing group is ",
          low_df |> pull(grp.col), " scoring ", low_df$percentage, "%.")
}


df <- data.frame(
    category=c('cat1', 'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat2', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat3'),
    value=c(1,0.8,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.5)
)

# returns category, value with highest mean value
gather_info(df, category, maxm=TRUE)

# returns category, value with lowest mean value
gather_info(df, category, maxm=FALSE)

# does not work
paste_info(df, category)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that inside `paste_info` you have to use `{{` to pass the grouping column `grp.col` to `gather_info` as well as when you call `pull`. This is for the same reason why you have to use `{{` in `group_by` inside `gather_info`

In some sense `{{` translates e.g. `gather_info(df, {{ grp.col }}, maxm = TRUE)` to `gather_info(df, category, maxm = TRUE)`, i.e. you pass `category` to `gather_info`. Without `{{` the column name stored in `grp.col` will not be "injected" into the expression or function call. Hence, `gather_info` will take `grp.col` as is and interprets it as the name of the grouping column. But as there I no column with name `grp.col` in your data you get an error.

For more info on why `{{` is needed see [What is data-masking and why do I need {{?](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask.html).

```r
library(dplyr)

paste_info <- function(df, grp.col) {
  high_df <- gather_info(df, {{ grp.col }}, maxm = TRUE)
  low_df <- gather_info(df, {{ grp.col }}, maxm = FALSE)

  paste0(
    "Given your data, your best performing group is ",
    high_df |> pull({{ grp.col }}), " scoring ", high_df$percentage, "%",
    " and your worst performing group is ",
    low_df |> pull({{ grp.col }}), " scoring ", low_df$percentage, "%."
  )
}

paste_info(df, category)
#> [1] "Given your data, your best performing group is Cat1 scoring 90% and your worst performing group is Cat2 scoring 20%."
```

Comment: Hype thank you ^ I can understand why this is the case but do you mind explaining why this is the fix?

Comment: I edited my question an added an explanation in my own words and a reference to why we need `{{`.